# Error/Crash while using GMSPlacePicker pickPlaceWithCallback in Objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, gmsplacepicker

This error is crashing the app while trying to use GMSPlacePicker in objC

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'

The app is crashed at the point `[placePicker pickPlaceWithCallback:^(GMSPlace * _Nullable place, NSError * _Nullable error)`

The whole set code block is below:

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.631514, 51.4723);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(26.0765, 56.4395);
    GMSCoordinateBounds *viewport = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:northEast coordinate:southWest];
    GMSPlacePickerConfig *config = [[GMSPlacePickerConfig alloc] initWithViewport:viewport];
    GMSPlacePicker *placePicker = [[GMSPlacePicker alloc] initWithConfig:config];
    [placePicker pickPlaceWithCallback:^(GMSPlace * _Nullable place, NSError * _Nullable error)
    {
        if (error!= NULL && error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"PlacePicker error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);  
            return;
        }
         if (place != NULL && place != nil) {
            NSLog(@"PlacePicker cordinates: (%f, %f)", place.coordinate.latitude, place.coordinate.longitude);
         } else {
            NSLog(@"No place selected");
         }
    }];
```

Please help.

Comment: at which line your code broken ?

Comment: At this point    [placePicker pickPlaceWithCallback:^(GMSPlace * _Nullable place, NSError * _Nullable error)

Comment: did you provide key for these in appdelegate : GMSServices.provideAPIKey("Your key")
  GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("Your key") ?

Comment: Yes I did. The code was working before... But now it is crashing.

Comment: what the os version ?

Comment: iOS version is 10.3.1 and XCode Version 8.3.1

Comment: try to make  GMSPlacePicker property instead of local variable.

Comment: assuming that your bundle identifier is as same as what you have configured to get api key. A change should be made not sure if it is related to this error, but instead of `(error!= NULL && error != nil)` it should be `(error!= NULL || error != nil)`

Comment: I tried @property(nonatomic, strong) GMSPlacePicker *placePicker; and (error!= NULL || error != nil).
But the still the same crash

Comment: Probably Place information could be nil. try by commenting following code if (place != NULL && place != nil) {
            NSLog(@"PlacePicker cordinates: (%f, %f)", place.coordinate.latitude, place.coordinate.longitude);
         } else {
            NSLog(@"No place selected");
         }

Comment: i tried with empty block too.. still it's crashing at the block start.

Comment: I updated the GooglePlacePicker Pods, now they are using GMSPlacePickerViewController and delegate methods instead of GMSPlacePicker. So far working fine. No crash.

Comment: @AshaAntony can you put sample code here, how it has worked for you..
here is my question i have asked today.. i am facing issue while doing this same feature.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49856173/i-want-to-display-google-place-picker-for-restaurants-using-gmsplacepickerviewco?noredirect=1#comment86729791_49856173