# i want to display google place picker for restaurants using GMSPlacePickerViewController, below are the code i am trying from developers.google.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps, google-places-api

[image]

i want to achieve above screenshot output in one of my app below is the sample code i am looking at in developers website.

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/placepicker

```
GMSPlacePickerConfig *config = [[GMSPlacePickerConfig alloc] initWithViewport:nil];
GMSPlacePickerViewController *placePicker = [[GMSPlacePickerViewController alloc] initWithConfig:config];
placePicker.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:placePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

GMSPlacePickerViewController is not visible to class it seems.

below attached is the error i am getting while putting this code to my class. 
[image]

Let me know if anyone of you have worked on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you import the Google Maps SDK? How? CocoaPods?

Comment: Yes using pod only..

Comment: And is the class present in the pods of your project? Did you do the `#import someHeaderFileForThatClass`?

Comment: no this GMSPlacePickerViewController class is not present in any one of the pods.

i checked all frameworks, 
1) GoogleMaps, 
2) GooglePlace 
3) GooglePlacePicker

thats why i have confusion that m i doing anything wrong here ?

Comment: What versions of Google API do you use ?

Comment: i am using the recent one only..
i have re-downloaded all pods today..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169108/discussion-between-maheta-dhaval-k-and-larme).